# I can't start the map on my location

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to start google maps in my position, but I can not, but I can put a marker at the position you want it to be Initial. I need your help please. I searched a lot here, but nothing has worked for me.

Best Regards

> Code

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    getSreenDimanstions();
    fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

    map = fragment.getMap();    

    bNavigation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNavigation);


      LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
      Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
      if(location!=null){

            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

             miPosicion = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(miPosicion).title("Start"));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
            .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        obtenerItems(map);




      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#target_location) which uses:

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 17.0f);
theMap.animateCamera(update);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the exact current location, you will be better off calling

`requestLocationUpdates(..)`

rather than

`getLastKnownLocation(..)`

and then implementing a `LocationListener` to listen to changes in location and act accordingly. For more information regarding LocationListener refer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

And on a side note: you seem to have initialized two `LatLng` types(`latLng` and `miPosicion`) with the exact same value and have not put either to full use.